# To Show$ Ax=y$ has no Solutions given that A is a 3x3 non invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to answer the following question:

> Given that A is a 3x3 matrix where the last row is the sum of the first two rows show  that$ Ax=y$ has no solutions. $y \in R^3$

I was thinking that since A is non invertible as $det(A) == 0$ and the number of pivots in A is 2, this means that when you augment A with the vector y, $\begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\y_2 \\y_3 \end{bmatrix}$  , you get $$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & x_3 &y_1\\z_1 & z_2 & z_3 &y_2\\(x_1 + z_1) & (x_2 + z_2) & (x_3 + z_3) & y_3 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Which, when reduced gives:
$$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & x_3 &y_1\\z_1 & z_2 & z_3 &y_2\\(0) & (0) & (0) & y_3 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

This means that there will be one free variable and only an arbitrary solution exists.

That is my reasoning but somehow it just doesn't feel like thorough enough or not even answering the question correctly.

Could someone give me some help with this question.  Thanks

Comment: The question makes no sense. Whether there are solutions depends on what $A$ is, and on what $y$ is. Given $A$, there exist $y$ for which there are no solutions, but also there exist $y$ for which there are infinitely many solutions. About all you can say is that there is no $y$ for which there is a unique solution.

Comment: Also, in your "reduction", you have to do the same thing with the last column that you do with the other three, so the lower right entry should be $y_3-y_1-y_2$.

Comment: THe question also states that $y$ is a vector but other than that, that is the exact wording of a question from a university exam paper.   I did think the same as you, there exists no y for which there is a unique solution.

Comment: Well, even university exam papers sometimes have mistakes (but I hope it wasn't one of mine!).

Answer (score 5):

If $y_3=y_1+y_2$ there are infinitely may solutions.

Comment: Right, but the question asks me to "show" that there are no solutions.  Also $y_3$ does no equal $y_1 + y_2$  the vector $y$ is augmented to the vector A.

Comment: If there are no solutions, then $\|Ax-y\|^2 > 0$

Comment: So what would be the best way to show that?